# Add a line in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I should add a line in the file *linux/drivers/pci/quirks.c* of the Linux Kernel. I never modified/compiled the Linux Kernel, what is the best way to do that? I need to compile the entire Kernel to add a single line? Or can I write only a patch to apply to the current Kernel? And what happens if a new kernel version will be released?

Comment: Is this just for debugging purpose. Or you want it to be in the mainline kernel?

Comment: @ChristinaJacob just for debugging purpose

Comment: For this certain modification you have to recompile entire kernel.

Comment: You. Have to build the kernel in this case.